# calculate a summation or a complex integral!

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, complex-integration

I am here again! This time is a complex integral question! I can not work it out by myself!

Consider 
$I(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}g_n(x)$ and $g_n(x)=\frac{1}{i(2n+1)-x}$, where x is a real variable and i is the imaginary unit.

The goal of this question is to calculate the sum above by transforming it into a complex integral. The hint is to show that $I(x)=\int_Cf(z)\frac1{z-x}dz$ by introducing z as a complex number and $f(z)=\frac1{2\pi i}(\frac1{e^z+1})$ and choose a proper contour C for integration at the same time. Then calculate the integral to get $I(x)$

From my point, there must be a connection between the singularities of $f(z)$ and the $i(2n+1)\pi$ in $g_n(x)$ and I need to use the residue. Then, game is over.

Comment: Done yet, only to find this way not working! This is exactly why I'm here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof sketch that uses the fact that $f(z) + f(-z) = 1$:

- Since $I(x) = -I(-x)$, you can assume without loss of generality $x < 0$. The semicircular contour $$
  C_N = \{x/2+iy: -2\pi N < y< 2\pi N\}\cup \{x/2 + 2\pi N e^{i\theta}:-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2\}
  $$contains the first $2N$ poles of $f(z)$. In the limit as $N\rightarrow\infty$, this will include all the poles of $f(z)$, but never contains $x$, and you can show the value of $\int_{C_N}f(z)/(z-x)dz$ will go to $-I(x)$.
- Consider $f(-z)/(z-x)$ using the semicircular contour $$
  C^-_N = \{x/2+iy: -2\pi N < y< 2\pi N\}\cup \{x/2 - 2\pi N e^{i\theta}:-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2\}.
  $$This contour contains none of the poles of $f(-z)$ for any $N$, but does contain $x$ for $N > -x/(4\pi)$. You can show from this that $\int_{C^-_N}f(-z)/(z-x)dz = f(-x)$ for large $N$.
- As $N\rightarrow\infty$, you can show the semicircle part of the integrals of $f(z)/(z-x)$ over $C_N$ and $f(-z)/(z-x)$ over $C_N^-$ to to zero. From this, you can show $$
   I(x) + f(-x) = -\int_{x/2+i\infty}^{x/2-i\infty} \frac{f(-z)dz}{z-x}+\int_{x/2-i\infty}^{x/2+i\infty} \frac{f(z)dz}{z-x}  = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{x/2-i\infty}^{x/2+i\infty} \frac{dz}{z-x} = \frac{1}{2}
  $$
- Since $f(-x) = 1/(e^{-x} + 1)$, you can conclude that $I(x) = -\tanh(x/2)/2$.

Comment: So the answer is to choose the contour whose origin is at $x/2$ and utilize the property of the functions. I still can not figure out the '1/2' result in the last step of the third part.

Comment: @Yankang Any value between $x$ and $0$ works. I just chose $x/2$ because it's always true that $x < x/2 < 0$ if $x < 0$. The final integral equal to $1/2$ can be done explicitly: just substitute $z = x/2 + iy$ and expand into real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Well, the $''1/2''$ question above seems to be a little bit dumb now. The solution is really awesome! This is a really great practice! Thank you so much!

Comment: @eyeballfrog Do semicircle parts of the integrals $f(z)/(z-x)$ and $f(-z)/(z-x)$ really tend to zero? I mean $|e^z| = |e^{x+iy}|=|e^{x}|$ and there are parts of the semicircle where $x$ don't move much (near the imaginary axis.)